# Why do DAC/ADC and sound interfaces so often have the same number of Inputs and Outputs?

Tags: audio-interfaces

I have been looking at the Symphony I/O lately, and seeing that most configurations of it has the same number of inputs and ouputs. Persionally, I can't see a situation where I would need 32 outputs.
My question is, is there a reason why it generally has the same number of inputs and outputs, are there benefits of this that I'm not seeing?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

even in a post environment, mixing in the box,  you may find yourself needing more outputs than you might think at first.

are you patching in any phone patches for clients? - outputs

are you dealing with ISDN? - outputs

do you have any outboard gear you would like setting as inserts? - outputs

mixing beyond stereo (5.1 etc)? - outputs

headphones mixes? - outputs

Answer (score 3):

The primary reason is for people working in music production who prefer to mix on consoles instead of "in the box."

Comment: Are there more respons than this one, or is it just very normal to mix in the on consoles instead of "In the box", because I cant find one model/configuration of the interface I'm looking at that doesn't have the same number of inputs and outputs.

Comment: That's really it. You have to remember that the music recording/mixing side of the industry accounts for a MUCH larger market base than post or sound design. They're going to items that appeal to the broadest portion of that market, then "sell" it to the rest. The only significant interface that I'm aware of that has a different number of Ins and Outs is the Avid Omni I/O.